# unable insert data into two tables using spring data jpa

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I am new in Spring data JPA.I have two table `info` and `details`.
`details` table `CPDT_CP_ID` is Foreign Key and `CPDT_ID` is primary key.
`info` table `CP_ID` is primary key.

Details.java

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CP_ID")
private Info info;

public Info getInfo() {
    return info;
}

public Details() {

}

public Details setInfo(Info info) {
    this.info= info;
    return this;
} ////// Others getters and setters
```

info.java

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy = "info")
private Details details;

public CorpDetails getCorpDetails() {
        return corpDetails;
}
public void setDetails(Details details) {
        this.details = details;
}
```

In my controller.java

```
Detailsobj.setInfo(Info);
DetailsService.saveDetails(Detailsobj);
```

I am getting ORA-00904: `"CP_ID":` invalid identifier. But my doubt `CP_ID` is not `details` table, it's in info table. 
Please help to me where is my mistake.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `@JoinColumn` you should specify the name of the column that refers to the master table, the column that has a foreign key pointing to the master table's id. So in your case, if `CPDT_CP_ID` in `details` has a foreign key to the `CP_ID` of `info` table you should put:

```
@OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "CPDT_CP_ID")
private Info info;
```